# ERROR: "docker context create" requires exactly 1 argument

Tags: docker, docker-compose, windows-subsystem-for-linux, remote-server, docker-desktop

I'm trying to deploy an application using docker-compose through Docker Context. I'm using this guide: https://www.docker.com/blog/how-to-deploy-on-remote-docker-hosts-with-docker-compose/

The problem comes when I try to create a context. e.g.:  `docker context create test --docker "host=ssh://user@remotehost"`
I get this:

> "docker context create" requires exactly 1 argument. See 'docker
> context create --help'.

This only happens on Windows WSL, on Linux it works flawlessly.

I'm using docker **19.03.8** with Experimental Features enabled.

Comment: I would double check the version of the docker client in WSL and make sure it matches the one you use in you other linux

Comment: they are the same

Comment: did you resolve this issue in the end?

Comment: @AG yep, there are some hidden charachers in the command. i just typed everything again, and it worked. don't know how they got there tho.

Answer (score 34):

It's because of the dash character. Compare the two commands (notice the two dashes before "docker")

Failed command:
`docker context create test --docker "host=ssh://user@remotehost"`

Successful command:
`docker context create test ‐‐docker "host=ssh://user@remotehost"`

These dashes look the same but have different character codes, the command line interpreter treats them as letters

Comment: yeah, encountered it too, copy-paste from web , thanks :)

Comment: Can you please explain how these two lines are different? they look identical to me.

Comment: @MaiElshiashi 
when utf-8 decoded <br/>
‐‐docker (failed command) <br/>
\xE2\x80\x90\xE2\x80\x90\x64\x6F\x63\x6B\x65\x72 <br/>
--docker (successful command) <br/>
\x2D\x2D\x64\x6F\x63\x6B\x65\x72<br/>

dash at the bottom makes it gray telling it's a option in vscode pwd

Comment: Even copying your "Successful command" didn't work, but typing the dash instead of copy/paste fixed the issue for me. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

There were 2 issues combined in my case (M1 mac). Weird -- symbols copied from web + skip the quotes:

```
docker context create --docker host=ssh://user@ip xxx
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Options should go before context. ie :"docker context create --docker host=ssh://user@remotehost test".
See documentation: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/context_create/

Comment: Maybe Judah meant this @Raul `docker context create --docker "host=ssh://user@remotehost test `? You can see examples like this on the linked docs.

Comment: Yes I know. Same result.